# CodeIgniter htaccess mod_rewrite not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make the url into
`http://127.0.0.1/dev/blog/welcome` but when I type that it changes the url to `http://127.0.0.1/dev/blog/index.php/welcome`

But When I do  `http://127.0.01/dev/blog//welcome` it stays like that for some reason.

my .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and my config.php is configured

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/dev/blog/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Oh, and I did check if mod_rewrite is on and I'm using WAMP

Another info: I'm using Firefox but when I use IE(9) It doesn't change the url from
`http://127.0.0.1/dev/blog/welcome` to `http://127.0.0.1/dev/blog/index.php/welcome`

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried flushing your browser cache?

Comment: @Zenbait yes, I did ctrl+f5, shift+ctrl+r, clear my cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `RewriteRule`, add the NC and QSA flags. The QSA ensures that query strings are appended. Unless you are planning on CodeIgniter manage your css files, images, and robots.txt, leave out the penultimate line too.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also, check your `uri_protocol` in config.php. I've had some problems with WAMP not detecting it properly, and have had the most luck with setting it to `PATH_INFO` instead of `AUTO`.

Comment: The page seems to say "No input file specified. " when I do `http://127.0.0.1/dev/blog/welcome`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have set [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AcceptPathInfo) to `ON` in your apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are editing the file on your webroot dir and not on the application dir. I've struggled a little bit while trying to get this to work properly until I finally figured that was my problem